# How to receive data from field in Qlik Sense 3.0?

Tags: javascript, field, qliksense

I'm working on extesion for Qlik Sense 3.0 Application.

I've made same topic on qlik community, but didn't receive answer.

https://community.qlik.com/thread/231938

I hope someone here can help me here.

Ok. I have a function:

```
function whenMonthsSelected(fieldName){  

    var field = app.field(fieldName);  

    var fieldData = field.getData();  

    console.log("fieldData");  
    console.log(fieldData);  

    console.log(fieldData.rows.length);  
}
```

And when I execute it, I'm receiving in browser:

[image]

In the result i have array with 0 elements.

And my question is...
What should i do to receive array with 12 rows?

This array store 12 rows (Information about months). And I can receive data by clicking on tree. But in console I always receiving array with 0 element.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to close and re-open QS?

Comment: Looks like the rows are not loaded the time you console.log. You need to access them later.

Comment: As Roland suggested try and fetch the data with promise. Something like: `field.getData().then( function ( fieldData ) {
  console.log(fieldData.rows.length)
  });`

Comment: @Stefan Stoichev - Yes I tried to close and open QS many times.

Comment: @Roland Starke - I understand what data is not load when I'm trying to work with it

Comment: @Stefan Stoichev - I'm tried work with syntax like you suggest, but always I'm receiving "TypeError: myField.getData(...).then is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind to the OnData event. Data is loaded asynchronously into the rows collection. The following typescript example shows the idea.

```
getField(field: string): Promise<any> {
        let self = this.app;
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            try {                    
                let reply: any;

                let listener = function () {
                    self.field(field).OnData.unbind(listener); 
                    resolve(reply.rows);
                }

                self.field(field).OnData.bind(listener); 
                reply = self.field(field).getData();
            } catch (ex) {
                reject(ex);
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: Note that you will be limited to the first 200 rows by default. There is a parameter for the number of rows to return. See documentation. Still trying to figure out how to page though. The getMoreData() function doesn't work for me at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this code will do what you need:

```
var fieldValues = app.field("SomeFieldName").getData();
fieldValues.OnData.bind(function () {
    console.info("waitedForData>>>",fieldValues.rows);
});
```

Comment: Try to explain why this is tje appropriate solution